# What method to use for this(poison binomial or binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

The experiment E is to take a required computer science course. The outcomes are the grades
(A, B+,B, C+, C, D, F). Suppose the experiment is repeated 5 times, once for each of CS111, CS112,CS113, CS205, and CS206. Assuming that A, B+, B, D, and F are each given with
probability 1/10, that C+ is given with probability 2/10, and C is given with probability
3/10, let X count the number of distinct grades you receive in the 5 courses. How would i do this with unequal probabilities for the grades?

For P(X=0) under equally likely probability for grades i would just do P(SSSSS),P(SSSSS),P(SSSSS),P(SSSSS),P(SSSSS) where each P() represents a class with the same grade.
P(X=1)=P(NSSSS), P(SNSSS),P(SSNSS),P(SSSNS),P(SSSSN) where N=not same letter grade
..etc for X=2,3,4,5,6,7
but if we introduce unequal likely probability then that N could have 3 different probabilities now(1/10, 2/10, 3/10).